# Create subclass with a property that is a subclass of that parent's classes corresponding property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, typescript

```
class TableController {
    constructor(public x,public y){}
}
class Table  {
    public controller = TableController;
}

class SquareTableController extends TableController{
  constructor(public x, public y, public z){
      super(x,y);
      /* do other stuff with z */
  }
}
class SquareTable extends Table{
    public controller = SquareTableController;
}
```

TypeScript gives me the following error for the above code:

```
TS2415: Class "SquareTable" incorrectly extends base class "Table". 
  Types of property "controller' are incompatible. 
  Type 'typeof SquareTableController' is not assignable to type 'typeof TableController'.
```

Note SquareTableController has an an extra parameter in its constructor.

How can I do such an inheritance setup in TypeScript? I'm pretty sure I have done very similar things in C# and Java.

Playground available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20TableController%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%2Cpublic%20y)%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Table%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20controller%20%3D%20TableController%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SquareTableController%20extends%20TableController%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20x%2C%20public%20y%2C%20public%20z)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(x%2Cy)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F*%20do%20other%20stuff%20with%20z%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20SquareTable%20extends%20Table%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20controller%20%3D%20SquareTableController%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you intend of having a reference to the class (`controller = TableController`) and not to an instance (`controller = new TableController()`)?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, yes I deliberately have a reference to the class, not an instance of the class. That is the standard convention when creating AngularJS components

Comment: Your code compiles just fine in playground.

Comment: Hmm. compiling fine for me in playground as well. Let me compare to the original version from my project . .

Comment: looking into it right now. I think it may be because my constructor for SquareTableController may be different than the constructor for my TableController

Comment: Then update your question with the code that reproduces the problem, it will also be nice if you could share a link to a playground of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143731/discussion-between-johnsimer-and-nitzan-tomer).

Comment: One workaround that works is doing `public controller:any = TableController;` in `TableClass`

Comment: What's the point of this? Why do you even need to have those `controller` members if they have a static value?

Answer (score -1):

### Colons `:` for type annotations.

You need to use colons `:` for type annotations instead of equals signs `=`.

```
class TableController {
    constructor(public x, public y) {}
}

class Table {
    // type annotation
    public controller: TableController;
}

class SquareTableController extends TableController {
  constructor(public x, public y, public z) {
      super(x, y);
  }
}

// type annotation
class SquareTable extends Table {
    public controller: SquareTableController;
}
```

### Equals `=` and `new` for object assignment.

If the goal is to do an assignment not a type annotation, then we can use the equals sign with a call to the constructor.

```
class TableController {
    constructor(public x, public y) {}
}

class Table {
    // object assignment
    public controller = new TableController(1, 2);
}

class SquareTableController extends TableController {
  constructor(public x, public y, public z) {
      super(x, y);
  }
}

class SquareTable extends Table {
    // object assignment
    public controller = new SquareTableController(1,2,3);
}
```